# Django get all related values of the model

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

These are my models

```
class Order(models.Model):
    name = ...

class OrderDetail(models.Model)
    order = models.OneToOneField(Order,null=False)
    comment = ...

class LastUpdate(models.Model)
    order = models.OneToOneField(Order,null=False)
    date = ...
```

When I write Order.objects.all().values() it gives me a list which only contains `name`
But I need to get the `name,orderdetail__comment,lastupdate__date` values.

I can get them by writing

```
Order.objects.values('name','orderdetail__comment','lastupdate__date').all()
```

but there are a lot of related models to the order and I don't want to write all of them.

How can I get the all values of the related fields?

Answer (score 5):

First, you query by

```
orders = Order.objects.select_related('orderdetail__comment', 'lastupdate__date')
```

then, get values by

```
orders.values('name', 'orderdetail__comment', 'lastupdate__date')
```

Comment: it woks if you define related_name = in model.